# Thingsboard PE: Cassandra to PostgreSQL

Tags: thingsboard

My question would be, Is it possible to change from Cassandra to PostGreSQL in Thingsboard PE because I'm more comfortable with PostgreSQl, and I need only the JSON data to be queried.

It would be great to get some suggestions.

Comment: Cassandra and Postgres are very different types of data stores.  The first, perhaps bigger, question to ask is whether it makes sense to switch from a business logic point of view.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the response. Cassandra is much powerful than Postgres, but I feel comfortable using PostgreSQL.